# How to download a subdomain of a website competely in linux with wget or some other tools?

Tags: linux, download, wget, web-crawler

I want to download all the passages of http://source.yeeyan.org.
It has a lot of pages. E.g. http://source.yeeyan.org/?page=22202
So how to use wget or some other tools in linux to download them down?
Currently, i use the following parameters, but it does not work.

wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains yeeyan.org --no-parent source.yeeyan.org

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to wget there is also [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) whose sole purpose is to copy websites and thus may suit you better. It also has a GUI.